# Can we paste multiline code into Pyspark Shell

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to copy code from PyCharm into a pyspark-shell. Even a simple copy of two import statements leads to an error. Please see code snippet below

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here. It'll be so helpful if I can copy whole snippets of code into the shell (for e.g. copy pasting the contents of an entire python file). Is this meant to work?

```
>>> import subprocess
import pickle
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import pickle

    ^
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to run this:

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=code.py pyspark
```

It will run your script in pyspark shell.

Usually when I paste into pyspark the issue is the whitespace.